# Set edittext input type to google handwriting keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to set a specific keyboard (ex spanish, google handwriting input) when a user clicks to enter text on a `editText` field. One source mentioned that a fully-qualified class can be specified for `android:inputMethod`, but I am not sure what I would specify for these keyboards.

It also appears that this constant was deprecated in API level 3 and inputType should be used instead. But of all constants listed for `inputType`, there is no reference to the keyboards I would want.

What other ways can I set the different keyboards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input method cannot be controlled by apps, this is entirely the users choice.

---

You can assist with switching the input method by opening the system dialog, which allows that. But you cannot select an option.

---

There are two ways around this:

- Use your own custom keyboard. You then can just not use the system input methods at all.
- Root (the answer to every Android Sandbox problem)